# Doctrine on Symfony 2 accusing decimals of being doubles

Tags: php, doctrine, symfony

I am reading the Symfony 2 documentation, and I am stuck at [the model part of the book](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html).
the `$price` is a dicimal of scale `2` :

```
// src/Acme/StoreBundle/Entity/Product.php
namespace Acme\StoreBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="product")
 */
class Product
{
    // ...

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="decimal", scale=2)
     */
    protected $price;

    // ..
}
```

I generated setters and getters as stated on the docs via the console and gave me this on the same entity class:

```
/**
 * Set price
 *
 * @param dicimal $price
 */
public function setPrice(\decimal $price)
{
    $this->price = $price;
}
```

So Doctrine is using type hinting to require `$price` to be a decimal.
the problem is it constantly raising this exception:

```
Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to 
Acme\StoreBundle\Entity\Product::setPrice() 
must be an instance of decimal, double given,
```

this is how it called in the defaultCountroller:

```
// ...
public function createAction()
    {
    $product = new Product();
    $product->setName('A Foo Bar');
    $product->setPrice('19.99');
    $product->setDescription('Lorem ipsum dolor');

    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
    $em->persist($product);
    $em->flush();

    return new Response('Created product id '.$product->getId());
}
```

here they are passing in a string (may be a documentation bug) but even if I change it to a decimal, I keep getting the same exception.
fortunately I just shaved my hair, but please help me on this. what is the problem?

Answer (score 3):

\decimal is not a system class or type in PHP. Simply remove the type hint.

Comment: Yes I know that, the hint is there for a reason, and it is supposed to work with it but it does not. The problem is still there.